# Tax wedge in labour market

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, labor-economics

I'm reading a book ( Macroeconomics - Institutions, Instability and the Financial System )  and on page 62, the authors define tax wedge as the "difference between the real consumption wage and  the real product wage". Should I understand this as a subtraction?

The real consumption wage is measured as $\frac{W}{P_c}$, where $W$ is the after-tax wage that employees receive, and $P_c=P(1+t_v)$ with $t_v$ being the indirect tax rate (VAT, etc).

The real product wage is the wage paid by firms to workers, and is measured by $W^{gross}/P$ where $W^{gross}=W(1+t_d)$ with $t_d$ being the direct tax rate(social securities contributions, etc).

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Sounds more like a ratio than a difference. I think the sentence is the book is misleading. Other uses of tax wedge are also usually ratios. (Googling "tax wedge" finds a few.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [OECD website](https://data.oecd.org/tax/tax-wedge.htm),

> **Definition of Tax wedge**
>
> Tax wedge is defined as **the ratio** between the amount of taxes paid by
>   an average single worker (a single person at 100% of average earnings)
>   without children and the corresponding total labour cost for the
>   employer. The average tax wedge measures the extent to which tax on
>   labour income discourages employment. This indicator is measured in
>   percentage of labour cost.

So here, it is a ratio, but *not* between wages, but rather of the *direct* tax burden (including social security contributions), as a percentage of total labor cost (i.e of total reward of labor). But it does *not* include indirect taxes.

As you can see, there are different ways to define the concept (extending it to include indirect taxes makes sense -the problem would be to measure it at that level).But it appears that in general we are talking about a ratio rather than a difference.

To reconcile, it is the "difference (in absolute terms maybe) between the real consumption wage and the real product wage" *as a percentage of real product wage*.